# UWP Application in Disconnected Env

Tags: sqlite, winrt-xaml, uwp

Can someone suggest a good project sample for UWP application which works in disconnected environment

Thanks in advance,
Denuka

Comment: By disconnected, you mean offline ?

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing, Shen wrote a good one.

> http://www.shenchauhan.com/blog/2015/11/25/sqlite-and-uwp

The takeaway is, offline requires an offline data store, and SQLite now ships as part of the universal platform. So, definitely, use SQLite.

Best of luck!

Comment: Hi Jerry, Thanks for your reply , Actually i downloaded this example earlier which is very good , I gained good knowledge from that . My scenario is to store data in local device (SQLite db) in disconnected environment and push data to Azure data base once the connection is available. Thanks in advance , Denuka

Comment: Disconnected Environment = Offline

Comment: I no longer understand your question. Your comment (above) seems to say that my answer is the answer you wanted. But then you say it is not. I guess I just don't understand what you want. Perhaps you have a different question? If you do, be sure and ask a new question and not build on this existing one.